# variadic template deduction with two template argument fails

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, c++20

When I have the class:

```
template <std::same_as<char> ... Indices>
struct MIndices {
        std::tuple<Indices...> indices;
        MIndices() = delete;
        constexpr explicit MIndices(Indices... args) : indices(args...) {
        }
};
```

The following call works:

```
    MIndices myI('i', 'j', 'l', 'z');
```

But changing the template to the following:

```
template <size_t Dims, std::same_as<char> ... Indices>
struct MIndices {
        std::tuple<Indices...> indices;
        MIndices() = delete;
        constexpr explicit MIndices(Indices... args) : indices(args...) {
        }
};
```

And then calling it with

```
    MIndices<4> myI('i', 'j', 'l', 'z');
```

suddenly fails to deduce the arguments.

Why and how can I fix this?

So in principle I would just like to have a compile-time way to specify
the number of tuple arguments. If this is a bad way for doing it please tell me.

I am using c++20. (gcc-12.1)

Comment: "*If this is a bad way for doing it please tell me.*" This is a bad way. The variadic template *already* tells you the number of arguments, i.e. `sizeof...(Indices)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Dims` should equal the number of parameters passed, you should use the `sizeof...` operator instead of letting the caller specify the size.

---

CTAD (class template argument deduction) only works when all template arguments of the class are deduced.

The workaround is to let all arguments be deduced. You can wrap the class that deduces the indices into another one that can have the size given explicitly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <size_t Dims>
struct wrapper {
    template <std::same_as<char> ... Indices>
    struct MIndices {
        std::tuple<Indices...> indices;
        MIndices() = delete;
        constexpr explicit MIndices(Indices... args) : indices(args...) {
        }
    };
};
    
int main() {
   wrapper<4>::MIndices myI('i', 'j', 'l', 'z');
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/edGMcvqvY)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I know that i can use sizeof.. but i need something to compare against. Which is what I use Dims for.

Comment: @user155370 "but i need something to compare against" ? I dont understand what you mean. `sizeof...(Dims)` is something you can comapre against. You only need to let the user specify `Dims` when it is different from the number of parameters passed.

Comment: The Dims template parameter comes from another templated type. How else would I make sure that sizeof...(args) == Dims if Dims is not a template parameter?

Comment: Ah sad. Your code actually does not compile for me.

Comment: in the question you write "I would just like to have a compile-time way to specify the number of tuple arguments" but in your example the size of the tuple is already determined by number of parameters passed. If the number of tuple elements is coming from else where its a different story. I think I understood now. Anyhow it doesnt change the answer

Comment: @user155370 why not? I just added a link to godbolt where it does compile with gcc

Comment: the link i added is for gcc 12.1

Comment: Ah yes im sorry. CLion reports an error but compiling it actually works. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

> Why and how can I fix this?

The **problem** is that when using class template argument deduction(aka CTAD), all template parameters must be determined by the deduction process or from default arguments. It is **not possible to explicitly specify a few arguments and deduce others**.

So to **solve** this you have to either explicitly specify all the template arguments or let all of them be deduced. So one way to fix this is:

```
MIndices<4, char, char, char, char> myI('i', 'j', 'l', 'z');
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yroe7zMbb)

---

Perhaps an more simplified example might help illustrate this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class Custom
{
    public:
    
        Custom (T1 x, T2 y, T3 z)
        {

        }
};
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    Custom c(3, 2.343, s); //works 

    //Custom<int> b(4, 2,343, s); //WON'T WORK

    Custom<int, int, std::string> k(4, 4, "s"); //works
}
```

---

> If this is a bad way for doing it please tell me.

You have the option of using `sizeof...(Indices)` so there doesn't seem to need to have an extra nontype template parameter of type `size_t`.